# Bash: order columns within groups?

Tags: bash, csv, sorting

I have a csv table which contains several thousands of rows, like so:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4
Bla Bla, 1, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 4, 2000, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 10, 63, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 1, 340, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 2, 65, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 4, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 10, 10, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 2, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 10, 99, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 1, 210, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 2, 1000, Bla bla
```

I would like to order two columns via bash in a terminal (on macOS if this matters).

a) The second column should be ordered numerically 1, 2, 4, etc. and the corresponding line with it, i. e. like:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4
Bla Bla, 1, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 1, 340, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 1, 210, Bla bla
...
```

b) In a second step, the third column should be ordered numerically within the group they are in. For example all cells should be ordered within group 1, then 2 etc, the final result (in my example should then look like:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4
Bla Bla, 1, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 1, 210, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 1, 340, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 2, 65, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 2, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 2, 1000, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 4, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 4, 2000, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 10, 10, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 10, 99, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 10, 63, Bla bla
```

How can this be done?

**Edit:**

I tried `sort -k2,2 input.csv | sort -k 3,3 > output.csv`. However, the output shuffles the groups in column 2 again while the third column is correctly ordered.

Comment: SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: You are right. Updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# write only header to new_file
head -n 1 file > new_file

# sort file without header (with GNU tail) and append to new_file
tail -n +2 file | sort -t ',' -k 2n -k 3n >> new_file
```

Output to `new_file`:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4
Bla Bla, 1, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 1, 210, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 1, 340, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 2, 65, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 2, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 2, 1000, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 4, 100, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 4, 2000, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 10, 10, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 10, 63, Bla bla
Bla Bla, 10, 99, Bla bla
```

---

See: `man sort`

Comment: Hi Cyrus, looks great. However, this command ordered column 1 or am I wrong?

Comment: You can simply this by reading and immediately writing the header from inside a command group. `{ IFS= read -r header; printf '%s\n' "$header"; sort -t, -k2,2n -k3,3n; } > new_file`.

Comment: Yes, it is sorting *rows* based on field values, not sorting columns as independent entities. If you want the latter, you need a spreadsheet.

Comment: `sort -k2,2n -k3,3n input.csv > output.csv ` did the trick for me.